# How do I inject a variable into an angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to create a filter that will concatenate a path with an image name.
I store a constant path for images in a value defined on my app like this:

```
app.value('config', { siteID: '29', apiRoot: 'http://localhost:54003/api', imageRoot: '/Content' });
```

Now in my filter I want to inject the config object and use it in my filter:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.filter('imageRoot', ['config', imageRoot]);

function imageRoot(config) {
    return function (imgName,config) {
        return config.imageRoot + '/' + imgName;  // config is undefined
    };
};

})()
```

Called from html like this:

```
<img src="{{post.Icon | imageRoot}}" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `config` argument from filter function, because you already have access to the `config` in the inner scope and specifying it in the function argument will create a new variable for the innerscope with no value assigned to it.

```
function imageRoot(config) {
    return function (imgName) { //<-- Remove from here
        return config.imageRoot + '/' + imgName;  
               //^__ This is already accessible from the outer scope
    };
};
```